# Using "Enter the" to introduce a topic

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrase-requests

I am writing an article for my school magazine on the ASCII encoding system and need your help choosing the right set of words.

This part of the article deals with the shortcomings of the Morse code and introduces the ASCII system with its advantages.

This is how it goes,

> Perhaps the biggest disadvantage is its steep learning curve, it is
>   difficult to grasp and simply not worth the time and effort. *Enter the
>   ASCII system*.

And then it goes on about how ASCII is much superior than Morse code.

Is this correct? If not, what else could be used in its place?

Edit: Would a comma after enter help?

> Enter, the ASCII system. It was designed to make transmissions...

Comment: You need to understand the referenced metaphor.  You're watching a circus.  The elephants have just put on a performance and are leaving the center ring.  Next, the ASCII system enters the ring and *really* wows the audience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is writing advice and otherwise a question that shows no research.

Comment: The question is awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "enter the ASCII system" works perfectly! I would suggest that you start a new paragraph right after that sentence though.

Also, the grammar in your list about the problems of Morse Code is not as smooth as it could be. Try the following sentence instead:

> Perhaps the biggest disadvantages are its steep learning curve and its
>      difficulty to grasp, which may simply make it not worth your time and effort. *Enter
>      the ASCII system.*

Comment: Thanks @jmrpink. Would a comma after "Enter" be wrong? `Enter, the ASCII system`

Comment: The rule I follow on commas at the beginning of sentences is from my 3rd year high school English teacher. She advised against using commas unless there are 3 or more words before the comma. I know it's not very concrete advice, but I would suggest you don't add a comma. Someone else might have more textbook-definition answer and reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

"Enter the ASCII system." "Enter" is simply an introduction word to emphasize something not quite anticipated that follows. That "something" (ASCII) appears to be a solution for the issue at hand.